# Form: Data submission from form to mysql database table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

Click on Submit button open a blank action.php neither any error message nor data insertion in table.

Request if someone can share clean code for action.php or guide me on the same.  I have my database login credential in connection.php

I have following code for my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="action.php" method="Post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vlocation">Location:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <?php 
            $reg=$thisitem['location'];
            $sql= "select  id, location from location";          
            $res= mysql_query($sql);    
            $sql1= "select  * from location where id='$reg'";            
            $res1= mysql_query($sql1);
            $thiscat =mysql_fetch_array($res1);          
            ?>                                  
            <select name="vlocation" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $thiscat['location']; ?>">                  
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select location</option>
                <option value="<?php echo $thiscat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $thiscat['location']; ?></option>
                <?php  
                while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($res)){?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $rows['id']?>"> <?php echo $rows['location'];?> </option>
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vtype">Category:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <?php 
            $reg=$thisitem['vtype'];
            $sql= "select  id, type from vtype";             
            $res= mysql_query($sql);    
            $sql1= "select  * from vtype where id='$reg'";           
            $res1= mysql_query($sql1);
            $thiscat =mysql_fetch_array($res1);          
            ?>                                  
            <select name="vtype" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $thiscat['type']; ?>">                  
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select venue category</option>
                <option value="<?php echo $thiscat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $thiscat['type']; ?></option>
                <?php  
                while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($res)){?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $rows['id']?>"> <?php echo $rows['type'];?> </option>
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>                    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vname">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vname" placeholder="Enter venue name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vseo">SEO:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vseo" placeholder="Enter venue seo string">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vpremium">Premium:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="text class="form-control" name="vpremium" placeholder="Enter PREMIUM if venue is premium">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vrank">Rank:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="vrank" placeholder="Enter venue rank">
        </div>
    </div>                    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vcontact">Contact:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vcontact" placeholder="Enter venue contact numbers">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vcapacity">Capacity:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vcapacity" placeholder="Enter venue capacity">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vprice">Price:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vprice" placeholder="Enter venue price details">
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vaddress">Address:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <textarea name="vaddress" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter venue address"><?php echo $thisitem['vaddress']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vinclusions">Inclusions:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <textarea name="vinclusions" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter inclusions"><?php echo $thisitem['vinclusions']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vspaces">Spaces:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <textarea name="vspaces" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter spaces available in venue"><?php echo $thisitem['vspaces']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vaccommodation">Accommodations:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vaccommodation" placeholder="Enter accommodation details">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vimages">Image Gallary URL:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vimages" placeholder="Enter image gallary url">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vdetails">Details:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <textarea name="details" class="summernote form-control" data-height="200" data-lang="en-US" placeholder="Enter venue details"><?php echo $thisitem['vdetails']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vmap">Google Map Code:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <textarea name="map" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter google map code"><?php echo $thisitem['vmap']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vmtitle">Meta Title:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <textarea name="vmtitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter meta title"><?php echo $thisitem['vmtitles']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vmkeyword">Meta Keyword:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <textarea name="vmkeyword" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter meta keywords"><?php echo $thisitem['vmkeyword']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vmdescription">Meta Description:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <textarea name="vmdescription" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter meta description"><?php echo $thisitem['vmdescription']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>                       
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="vstatus">Status:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">     
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="status"> Enable</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> -->
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

As I have very little knowledge of PHP hence looking for forum support. Poitive in anticipation

Comment: Please share your action.php

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Anyway, as mentioned, if the problem is what happens when the form is posted to action.php then of course we need to see the code for that script. We can't fix what we can't see. If you are getting a blank page it suggests the script crashed in some way, but that you don't have PHP error reporting switched on. You can google ways to enable this. Also check if PHP errors are being logged to disk, and then you can get there instead. Once you have the precise error message it will be a lot easier to diagnose the problem. This is the first basic step you need to take when debugging an error.

Comment: following is my action.php (I am trying with one field only for testing purpose). It shows following message (Connected successfullyArrayNew venue record created successfully. Record is being created but blank as form values are lost during submission.

Comment: <?php

// Create connection
include('../dbConfig.php');

// Define variables
$vlocation = isset($_POST['vlocation']);
$vtype = isset($_POST['vtype']);
$vname = isset($_POST['vname']);
$vseo = isset($_POST['vseo']);

print($_POST);

$query = "INSERT INTO venue (vname) VALUES ('$vname')";

if ($db->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "New venue record created successfully";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $db->error;
}

?>